# Organization Browser Webpart is missing from publishing site website selector

Tags: organization-browser

I am trying to find the organization browser webpart in my publishing site’s webpart selector, but it is missing there. As shown in the screen shot below:

[image]

How can I add organization browser web part to a page in a publishing site?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the SharePoint Server Standard Site Collection features.

If this couldn't solve your problem , then you need to activate PortalLayouts feature on a site collection

```
stsadm -o activateFeature -name "PortalLayouts" -url "http://SiteCollectionURL" –force
```

[Reference](http://brainlitter.com/2011/08/12/some-social-collaboration-web-parts-missing/)

Answer (score 0):

You must have to perform User Profile Synchronization to have the organizational data within SharePoint to be displayed in the Organization Browser WebPart.

You have to crawl sps3://siteurl in a content source,for your site collection

[Organizational browser](https://sampathlive.wordpress.com/2010/03/03/organization-browser-in-sharepoint-2010/)